# How can show a Dialog with RecycleView

Tags: android

I have an Android activity with a RecycleView and I have implemented a ClickEvent on this RecycleView.

If I try to click on one items, I want to display a Dialog with another RecycleView.

So this is my activity code:

```
public class ResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<Result> lista= new ArrayList<Result>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewResult;
    private ResultsAdapter pAdapter;
    private ResultXResultAdapter prAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try{


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.results_activity);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        ResultDAO manager = new ResultDAO(this);
        lista=manager.getResults();

        pAdapter = new ResultsAdapter(lista, new ResultsAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(Result item) {

                    try{
                        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ResultActivity.this);

                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.result_modal);
                        recyclerViewResult = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_result_view);
                        dialog.setTitle("Parametri");

                        prAdapter = new ResultXResultAdapter(item.getListaParametri());
                        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                        recyclerViewResult.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                        recyclerViewResult.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                        recyclerViewResult.setAdapter(prAdapter);


                        dialog.show();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        Log.e("","");
                    }
            }
        });
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(pAdapter);
       // prepareMovieData();
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
}
```

If I run my application and I try to click on one items, I have null exception. The problem is in this line code:

```
recyclerViewResult = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_result_view);
```

after this code, the recyclerViewResult is null,  but should not be null.

Comment: I really recommend to use fragment dialog in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your `RecyclerView` is returning `null` is because you're calling `findViewById` without the correct view prefix. Because you're using a custom layout in your `Dialog` you should use a `LayoutInflater` to inflate the layout then use the inflated view object to find the `RecyclerView` that belongs in the `dialog` like so:

`View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.result_modal, null);
recyclerViewResult = (RecyclerView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_result_view)
dialog.setContentView(dialogView)`